# How can I purchase skins for Minecraft through the Xbox/Microsoft Store?

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

How can I get money on the Xbox 360 Minecraft game to purchase skins at the Minecraft store?

I purchased a Minecraft Mojang prepaid card and would like to use it on the Xbox 360, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so to make purchases on the Xbox you can only use prepaid xbox cards, or pay directly using a credit card.

Mojang prepaid cards don't work on Xbox unless they have a Xbox symbol on them.